# What is the adjective for "awaiting opportunities"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am searching for a word to describe a group of people who **are ready for change** but **desperately need a catalyst**.

> I understood that my country needs transformative economists just like a seed needs water to grow and decided to devote my life to being the water of my ____ people.

The ideas that I have are:"brimming with **expectations**" or "**hopes**". As you see, the words that I have come up with don't really encapsulate the connotations that I want to imply. If possible, I would like to use a single word.

Also, I think my sentence sounds a bit awkward. Can anyone suggest me better revisions of my sentence?

Comment: How about "My country needs transformative economists like a seed needs water to grow, and I've decided to devote my life to being that water to my ___ people."? Alternatively, "Like a seed needs water to grow, my country needs transformative economists, so I've..."

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Consider *expectant*.

> **expectant** *adjective*
>   1 Having or showing an excited feeling that something is about to happen, especially something good.
>   ‘expectant crowds arrived early’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expectant)

Comment: If ' "brimming with expectations" ... [doesn't] really encapsulate the connotations that I want to imply', then neither does "expectant".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP wants a single word. Also, *expectant* has a somewhat more hopeful connotation than *brimming with expectations*.

Answer (score 1):

**[Agog](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agog)** is an apt word.

> agog /əˈgɒg  / ▸ adjective [predic.] very eager or curious to hear or
>   see something:

Answer (score 0):

Consider **yearning** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yearning))

> a tender or urgent longing *a yearning for justice*

or **thirsting** ([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thirsting))

> an ardent desire :  craving, longing *a thirst for success*

Comment: yeah, but İ can't say my thirsting country

Comment: @IlkinBayramli that's not the example you provided... my *thirsting* people works rather well, literally and figuratively.

Comment: I've absolutely heard "a people thirsting for change" before.